# Primefaces two messages getting displayed instead of one for ajax blur event

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have one row editable datatable. I have implemented email validation to one of the column where error message must display on blur of email field. This is working fine. I have a dialog with form to be displayed in the same page. Validation is implemented to this form also with on blur event. The dialog validation message gets displayed on blur but along with that the main form also displays the same validation message. This should not happen.

JSF page

```
<h:form id="lpcForm">

    <div id="content">

        <p:commandLink id="cmdLinkDelete" value="Delete"
            style="font-size:15px;padding-left:15px;" ajax="true"
            action="#{lpcBean.deleteRecords}" update=":lpcForm:lpcDataTable" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <p:commandLink id="cmdLinkAdd" value="Add" style="font-size:15px;"
            onclick="dlg.show()" />


        <p:messages id="lpcInfoMsg" for="lpcInfoMessages" showDetail="true"
            autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
        <p:messages id="lpcErrMsg" showDetail="false" redisplay="false"
            styleClass="messagesClass" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:dataTable var="lpcData" id="lpcDataTable" widgetVar="lpcTable"
            value="#{lpcBean.lpcItems}" selection="#{lpcBean.selectedRows}"
            editable="true" scrollable="true" scrollWidth="80%"
            rowKey="#{lpcData.LPCID}" rendered="true"
            scrollHeight="75% important!" resizableColumns="true"
            tableStyle="table-layout:auto;width:100% important!; height:100% important!;padding-left:15px important!;"
            styleClass="datatable">

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{lpcBean.onEdit}" />
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{lpcBean.onCancel}" />
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:15px" />


            <p:column headerText="LPC ID" style="width:20px"
                sortBy="#{lpcData.LPCID}">
                <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.LPCID}" />
            </p:column>



            <p:column headerText="Email" style="width:75px"
                sortBy="#{lpcData.email_Address}">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{lpcData.email_Address}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{lpcData.email_Address}" style="width:100%"
                            label="emailAddress" validatorMessage="Invalid Email Format">
                            <f:validateRegex
                                pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
                            <f:ajax event="blur" render=":lpcForm:lpcErrMsg" />
                        </p:inputText>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .

            <p:column style="width:10px">
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
        <p:blockUI block="lpcDataTable" trigger="cmdLinkDelete,cmdLinkAdd">  
    LOADING<br />
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajaxLoader.gif" />
        </p:blockUI>

    </div>
</h:form>


<p:dialog header="Add LPC" id="lpcDlg" widgetVar="dlg" rendered="true"
    appendToBody="true" resizable="true" modal="true">
    <h:form id="addLpc">

        <div align="center">

            <p:messages id="lpcDlgMsg"  showDetail="false"
                autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
            <h:panelGrid id="addLpcForm" columns="2" appendToBody="true">

                <h:outputText value="LPC ID" />
                <p:inputText id="lpcId" value="#{lpcBean.lpcId}" required="true">
                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="lpcDlgMsg" />
                </p:inputText>
                .
                .
                .
                .
                .
            </h:panelGrid>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <p:commandButton id="submitButton" value="Submit" ajax="true"
                update=":lpcForm:lpcDataTable" action="#{lpcBean.formSubmit}"
                oncomplete="dlg.hide()" />
            <p:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" ajax="true"
                onclick="dlg.hide()" />

        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The message with id **lpcErrMsg** is the one that i am displaying on blur in the main page when email format is wrong.And this message gets displayed with dialog field validation also although i have never referred to this id to be rendered in the dialog.

The message with id **lpcDlgMsg** is the message that  i am displaying inside the dialog with widgetvar **dlg** on blur.As of now i have implemented blur event validation for the first **required** field in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

One way `<p:messages ... globalOnly="false" />`. Other way is to use `<p:ajax ... listener="#{bean.renderMethod}" />` and in `<p:messages ... rendered="#{bean.render}" />`. renderMethod is used to set boolean render to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the autoUpdate="true". Just update the message ids based on the requirement.